# Angular form with dynamic name are not initializing

Tags: angularjs, forms, dynamic

I have a few objects and a form. Each object should remember the state of it's form (mainly, dirtyness).

I'm trying to create a form with a dynamic name like such:

```
 <form name="selectedObject.form">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="selectedObject.name" required>
 </form>
```

My problem is:

1. I make the first form dirty
2. Change the selected object
3. The form is considered dirty

I would think the using a dynamic name to the form would set a watch and have it rerender dynamically.
Anyway to do this?

Here's a plunkr simulating the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NAHVfhCf6RhpJHPGl7El?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would like to have it work, I think not. I also see problem in your code, namely form declaration. Name is string so now your form's name is always literal `selectedObject.form`. I think you ment to write it as `<form name="{{ selectedObject.form }}">` and have actual name for the form instead of `{}` you have assigned now?

You could add `isDirty` as new property to your `objects` and toggle it manually.

```
$scope.objects = [{
  name: 'Object1',
  type: 'Type1',
  form: 'form1',
  isDirty: false
},{ 
  name: '',
  type: 'Type2',
  form: 'form2',
  isDirty: false }];

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="setSelected()">Change selected</button>
  <form name="{{ selectedObject.form }}">
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="selectedObject.name" 
           ng-change="selectedObject.isDirty = true">
    {{ selectedObject.isDirty }}
  </form>
</body>
```